# Workflow Rule options

Tags: workflow

In workflow rule there are two checkbox options are there

`created, and every time it's edited` and `created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria` what is the main difference between these options

**for first checkbox also,
we have criteria met options are there for down then what is the difference apart from time dependent workflow actions,can anyone suggest the answer**

[image]

Comment: There are thousands of example available in Salesforce docs and on google as well. Did you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria

means that only when the record wasn't meeting the criteria and after the update met it, then this workflow should trigger.

Unlike

> created, and every time it's edited

Where the record will always trigger the workflow regardless of if it met the criteria before or not.

Example:

Workflow Criteria :
% Completed > 50

Action : Send Email.

We have a record A.%_Completed = 45

We make an edit and put Completed at 75.

Both of the workflow would rise and send an email on that case. But If we changed it from 75% to 100% Only the

> created, and any time it's edited

Would.

Hope this clarified things up.

Comment: It's just an example of a field you could have.